# Get current Windows user session ID in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, session, winlogon

I need to know if a session belongs to the current user. I thought I would do something like this:

```
Public Function SessionID()
    Dim session_id = 0
    Dim user As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity
    user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Dim selectQuery As SelectQuery = New SelectQuery("Win32_LogonSession")
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery)
    For Each session As ManagementObject In searcher.Get
        If session("LogonID") = user.Name Then
            session_id = Convert.ToInt32(session("LogonID"))
        End If
    Next
    Return session_id
End Function
```

The `SelectQuery` returns a list of current sessions but I cannot find the current user's logon ID to compare against

Comment: How about Environment.UserName ?